# Kali Linux USB folder sharing

Tags: kali-linux, shared-folders

Can I somehow "share a folder" in Kali Live so it is accessible in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

**Share folder between Kali Live and Windows**

You can run your Kali Live from VirtualBox or VMware. Detailed official documentation can be found [here](https://kali.training/topic/booting-kali-in-live-mode/).

Then you should install *guest additions* in running Kali Live. Official documentation [here](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest).

And finally you will be able to create *Share folder* between Kali and Windows. Previous link to documentation also contains details about this setup.

---

**Running `samba` on Kali Live**

You can to do this by installing `samba` server package and configure it.

There are more Kali-specific examples you can get by googling. [How to Install and Configure Samba Server on Kali Linux](https://educationlinux.com/install-and-configure-samba-server-on-kali-linux-2018-4/) one of them.

The most detailed documentation you can get from [Samba project documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/).

Comment: Do I need more than one computer to use it? Because to login to Windows I need to exit Kali.

Comment: You can test your setup in Kali with `smbclient -L` command. I assume that you mean how to test `samba` setup. Or you mean something else?

Comment: To start the server i need to enter Kali, but I suppose that if I exit, which I need to do to login to Windows, the server stops. So I need another PC to access Kali and Windows at the same time? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I understand. My first assumption was wrong. I update my answer.